# Dowload exe files in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, executable

I am downloading an exe file in my extension in event page( script). it downloads it but gives an popup to user keep/discard. which is kind of annoying to the user to say yes/no whatever my extension will download.
Is there any way i can suppress it?

**function to download in event page is:**

```
maurl="https://myserver/myexe.exe"
    function DownloadFile(maurl, loc)
    {
        chrome.downloads.download(url:maurl,function (id){ 

        console.log(id)});
    }
```

the second parameter loc is to keep it at a particular location. is it possible to keep the downloaded file to a particular like home directory for the user?without user intervention or if we ask user then it should be 
once only.

Comment: does "maurl" stand for "malware url"? why you want to circumvent obvious security measures?

Comment: no, it sounds like myurl. i want to circumvent it, because it has many exe, .jnlp files which extension will download. so its not a good idea to popup user every time.

Comment: does the keep/discard only appears when downloading exe types? because with a different method my extension downloads files (pdf, png etc) without that alert.

Comment: Yes, it does it for exe like file only.